# UDeploy Create windows Service using Service Control Manager plugin

Tags: udeploy

I am trying to create new service using Create Service step in Service Control Manager plugin in udeploy but my step is failing while executing it. This is what I see in output window

```
sc.exe create 'MyServiceName' '/binPath=MyServicePath\n/start=auto\n/'
```

The link  https://developer.ibm.com/urbancode/plugindoc/ibmucd/microsoft-windows-services/1-2/steps/#create_service states that I have to pass argument in a newline-separated list of arguments but as you can see my arguments are passed in big single quote and I am not sure how to address this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by Passing argument like below in argument box for Create Service Step in UDeploy UI

```
binPath=[Press Enter]
MyServicePath=[Press Enter]
start=[Press Enter]
auto=[Press Enter]
```

Make sure there is no extra spaces at the end of each line.